# Observing a variable's state within a ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to wrap my head around ViewModels and how variables within are observed.  I would like to figure out how to observe variables within a ViewModel and trigger actions when they do change.   Please consider the following example code:

My Composable:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSetup(viewModel: myViewModel) {


    var whosTurn: Int? by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.whosTurn.value) }


    Column {
        Row {
            Text(text = "Current Turn = ${whosTurn}")
        }
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.newTurn()

            }) {
                Text(text = "Next Turn")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

My Viewmodel:

```
class myViewModel : ViewModel() {


   var whosTurn : MutableState<Int> = mutableIntStateOf(1)


    fun newTurn() {

        Log.i("tag",whosTurn.value.toString())

        whosTurn.value += 1

        if (whosTurn.value == 4) {
            whosTurn.value=1
            //sets limit of 3 player game
        }

    }



}
```

When I execute the simple program, if I click the button the output on the emulator shows "Current Turn = 1" constantly.  However if I look at my Log, the variable "whosTurn" is incrementing within the ViewModel as I would like.  How do I have the variable "whosTurn" observed correctly so that Current Turn increments?

Thank you so much in advance for considering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewModel you should define your variable like this:

```
 val _whosTurn = MutableStateFlow(1)
 val whowTurn = _whosTurn.asStateFlow()
```

In the screen, you can now collect it as state:

```
val whosTurn by viewModel.whowTurn.collectAsState()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code

```
val whosTurn: Int? by viewModel.whosTurn.observeAsState()
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but observeAsState() comes back as "unresolved reference".  My experience with that error has been I'm missing a dependency or import.  In my gradle I'm including: implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")  And implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2") and implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.4").  Any idea what I am missing?